# URL Rewrite HTACCESS GET

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Currently I'm using

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

To rewrite for example http://localhost/products.php to http://localhost/products

How would I add so that it would also rewrite http://localhost/products.php?category=all to http://localhost/products/all/

I don't really comprehend the code fully. Thanks!

Comment: you're looking at it backwards. you don't rewrite an ugly url to a pretty one. You code should be sending the pretty ones to the client, e.g. `<a href="/products/all/">`, and then converting them BACK to ugly for internal usage. modwrite only handles INCOMING urls. it doesn't translate OUTGOING ones.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, thanks. although im fairly certain my current htaccess code already does that right? i was just comprehending what it did incorrectly?

Comment: you'd have `rewriterule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?category=$2` or thereabouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these rules to add another url with a query string to redirect to SEO friendly URL. Also a couple of extra rules to prevent usage of old URL style.

```
RewriteEngine On

#redirect old url to pretty url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /+(.+)\.php\?category=([^&\s]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /+(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

#if request is for a real file or real directory do nothing.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#internally redirect uri to php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?category=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: this looks great, thanks, exactly what i was looking for, however when i try it and link to http://localhost/products/all/ it doesn't seem to go to http://localhost/products.php?category=all otherwise the rest works, big plus for the comments to explain what it does

Comment: seems RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^\.]+)/?$ $1.php?collection=$2 [NC,L] is the culprit, the redirect old to pretty url part actually points to http://localhost/products/all if you try to visit http://localhost/products.php?category=all but the file doesnt exist once you get there so it doesn't seem to actually access products.php or what else could be going wrong, any suggestions? thanks .. on further inspection it seems to try to access /products.php.php

Comment: When is this happening /products.php.php? Using the pretty URL?

Comment: yes only when accessing http://localhost/products/all not with http://localhost/products there's also something weird, if i remove my htaccess code completetly it still points http://localhost/products to http://localhost/products.php and works, very confusing

Comment: I modified the code a little for that 2nd to last rewriterule. Try that. First clear your browser cache or use another browser. That might be causing the weirdness.

Comment: your first code actually worked, its just me being confused. it showed a page without styling which i thought had to do with the #if request is for a real file or dir part so i commented it out and thats when it loaded .php.php, now that i have it uncommented again i realized its actually showing exactly what it should, the only issue is the css isn't loading for some reason, does it have to do with me using a relative path and not the full one? <link href="assets/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> sorry about the confusion

Comment: Yes add a `/` to front of your path. `href="/assets/css/stylesheet.css"` or add this to head section of your html. `<base href="/" />` That should fix the css.

Comment: You've been tremendous help! Which option is best practice? Should I already be referencing / by default? In that case the base option seems like bad practice? Thanks yet again!

Comment: Up to you really. I tend to use more absolute paths in my link tag either using full domain or `/` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . 1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

create file 1.php

```
#split the path by '/'
  $params     = split("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    define("FILE_PHP",".php");
    define("ERROR_404","404.php");
    define("INCLUDE_ADMIN","index.php");
    class Loader{

     public function __autoload($params) {
         if(isset($params[1])==TRUE){ 
          if (file_exists($params[1].FILE_PHP)) { 
             if(is_set($params[2])==true)
              $category=$params[2];
              require_once $params[1].FILE_PHP; 
              return true; 
          } 
           require_once ERROR_404; 
          return false; 
         }else{
          require_once INCLUDE_ADMIN; 
          return TRUE; 
         }
    } 
    }
    $loader=new Loader();
    $loader->__autoload ($params);
```